# Equivalent of QPixmap in android

Tags: android, performance, qt, bitmap

I have worked on Qt for sometime and familiar with `QImage` and `QPixmap`.

On android, I am using `Bitmap` class, and wanted to understand how `Bitmap` is designed in terms of performance. Is Bitmap like QImage or QPixmap? That is, is the internal bitmap pixel data stored in the same process as the application or somewhere in other process where it is more efficient for rendering?

Answer (score 0):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qpixmap.html#details

https://www.google.com/search?q=qpixmap+gui+thread

`QPixmap` uses an offscreen buffer that should only be used in the GUI thread.  And the raster engine of Qt makes it pretty efficient and work well.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/using-bitmap-class-object-to-draw-an-image/

I haven't programmed for Android yet, but just looking around for tutorials about graphics, a lot of them mention "drawables" and using the "Bitmap" class.

I bet it is pretty efficient.  You could also look into using OpenGL ES.  It opens up a lot of doors.

http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html

Here is a link to videos of the experts of Qt talking about performance:

http://qt-project.org/videos#c-91

Hope that helps.